# error 0xC00CE020: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: ... 'Publisher'

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app

Ok, I just run out of ideas.
I can't get UWP running on my Surface Pro 3.
I'm running W10 Pro (Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]) and VSEnterprise 2015 with Update 1.
Every time I create a new Universal Windows App Project, and try to open MainPage.xaml (or any other page), I get slammed with this message without a way around this.

```
System.Exception
The Appx package's manifest is invalid.

error 0xC00CE020: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 31, Column 6, Reason: Falta o atributo requerido 'Publisher'.

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

This is currently happening with every single solution, new and existing. 
I have already reinstall VS2015Update1 and W10SDK more than I can remember.
I have already try to debug deven.exe for this issue with no clue.

Comment: So the problem may not be the Visual Studio, it may be a problem with .Net framework, you may try to reinstall your os and see if that does help.

Comment: Thanks Grace, but reinstalling OS was currently not an option. Although I got it solved by removing again VS2K15 and some files left behind on Program Files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As faster as I report this, faster I would come up with an solution.
I uninstall every single software from VS2015 from program and features and every dependency.
Delete parasite folders from Program Files & PF(x86) related to Windows SDKs/VS2015 and it worked.
I got XAML files working again on UWP.